# my other if else statement is executing php

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have 3 forms with 3 radios each but executed one at a time because of random generator. If I click a radio, it will go to next page and will be checked by the if else statement. Now my problem is, when it gets answered and it's correct, it will output yes. However, my other if else statement of my other radio executes. Since it's not answered, it assumed that it was wrong, so it outputted no.

here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question and Answer</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php 
        //Creating random numbers
        $rid = rand(1,3);
    ?> 




    <?php 


    if ($rid == 1){

echo "

<form action='answer.php?id=1' method='post' id='quizForm' id='1'>


<ol>


    <li>
    <h3>What does HTML Stands For ?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='A' />
    <label for='answerOneA'>A) Hyper text markup language</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='B' />
    <label for='answerOneB'>B) Hyper turn mark lingo</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='C' />
    <label for='answerOneC'>C) Happy tissue mahatma life</label>
    </div>
    </li>




<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit1' value = 'Choose..'> 


</form>";

}


    if ($rid == 2){

echo "

<form action='answer.php?id=1' method='post' id='quizForm' id='1'>


<ol>


    <li>
    <h3>What does CSS Stands For ?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer2' id='answer2' value='A' />
    <label for='answer2A'>A) College Computer Studies</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer2' id='answer2' value='B' />
    <label for='answer2B'>B) Cascading Style Sheet</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer2' id='answer2' value='C' />
    <label for='answer2C'>C) Cascaded Style Sheet</label>
    </div>
    </li>




<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit1' value = 'Choose..'> 


</form>";

}

if ($rid == 3){

echo "

<form action='answer.php?id=1' method='post' id='quizForm' id='1'>


<ol>


    <li>
    <h3>What does PHP Stands For ?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer3' id='answer3' value='A' />
    <label for='answerOneA'>A) Hyper text markup language</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer3' id='answer3' value='B' />
    <label for='answerOneB'>B) Hyper turn mark lingo</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer3' id='answer3' value='C' />
    <label for='answerOneC'>C) Happy tissue mahatma life</label>
    </div>
    </li>




<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit1' value = 'Choose'> 


</form>";

}

    ?> 



</body>
</html>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question and Answer</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php

        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        $answer = array('A','B','C');


        $answer1= $_POST['answerOne'];
        $answer2= $_POST['answer2'];

        if($answer1 == $answer[0]){
            echo 'yes';
        }
        else if ($answer1 != $answer[0]){
            echo 'no';
        }
        else{

        }

        if($answer2 == $answer[1]){
            echo 'yes';
        }
        else if ($answer2 != $answer[1]){
            echo 'no';
        }

    ?>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I'm not 100 % sure of what you're asking, but try using `else if()` on the first page instead of several `if()`'s

Comment: it's a quiz program, If I choose an answer and it's correct, it will display yes, otherwise no. My problem is that the other if else of the other question will display even when I never answered it.

Comment: sounds like you need to add a check to make sure there is an answer before you do the checks to see if it's right. the if/else is going to run every time right now, and answer2 isnt going to be right, since nothing's there, and so the last else if will be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cleaner way to do it. Inside `is_correct` function, it check if particular answer exist in `$_POST`, if so it returns if the answer is correct:

```
function is_correct()
{
    $answer = array(
        'answerOne' => 'A',
        'answer2' => 'B',
        'answer3' => 'C',
    );

    foreach ($answer as $k => $v) {
        if (array_key_exists($k, $_POST)) {
            return $v == $_POST[$k];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

if (is_correct()) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: @rendell, this is how you should think in terms of programming. If you want to do the same thing several times - consider using functions. Nice solution, +1.